# Single Sign On using ADFS 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, single-sign-on, adfs2.0

How to put single sign on using adfs 2.0 (active directory federation services) give me the steps with examples..i use visual studio 2010 and linq for coding and  my project is based on school management system.

If there is another way to put single sign on in my project with using concept of active directory then also tell me that method.with suitable example.

**Is it possible to install adfs on local server.?**

i try to install it on virtual private server but i fail.due to operating system version problem.
if it is possible then give me details about it.

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: is there possible to install adfs on windows 7.with all required components of adfs..?

Comment: i try so much but i can't get it.?have u any idea then please tell me about it.?   that how i put single sign on service in my project with using concept of active directory..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the shortest possible instruction would be

1. install ADFS 2 on one of your servers, configure it to use your Active Directory
2. Install WIF runtime and WIF SDK 4.0 on your dev machine (this assumes you use VS2010)

   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17331

   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4451
3. create an empty web application
4. set authentication mode to "Windows", add authorization rule that prevents unauthenticated users (deny users="?")
5. add an STS reference (right click on references and pick "Add STS Reference"), point to your ADFS metadata (https://your.adfs.address/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml)
6. Go to ADFS and add a Relying party trust - provide the address of your appliaction (https://your.application.address)

However, most of these steps involve multiple actions where things go wrong. Do not be discouraged, in case of issues just ask questions.

Comment: Thankss  Wiktor Zychla....thank u so much...