# ADFS Authentication in C#.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, adfs

In my company we have a requirement from the client for SSO using ADFS. The client has provided the IDP certificate fingerprint and IDP target URL.

I tried doing some research on how to accomplish this but have not found what exactly is to be done. Can someone please guide me on how to proceed and what other information I should get from the client?

Comment: I did find this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609466/single-sign-on-using-adfs-2-0) . Might Prove helpful

Comment: Thanks kumar. But this post provides an option using Metadata file location. But in my case the client has only provided IPD certifcate fingerprint and Target URL.

Comment: In theory as a service provider, you only need to know (a) where to redirect the user to assuming that you have agreed on the protocol and (b) how you would validate the response. For example if you were a WS-Fed app and the IDP was ADFS, you'd create a WS-Fed sign-in request or sign-out request to https://adfs.contoso.com/adfs/ls?waction=.... and then validate the incoming token by doing signature validation using the WIF library where you provide the thumbprint.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the "client", you mean the client is the one using ADFS?

In which case, you have the URL, just navigate to:

https://IDP URL/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

and you have the metadata.

In terms of adding support into your application, use the NuGet OWIN package for WS-Fed or WIF as above. (OWIN is the modern way).